# Don't add "+" to linux kernel version

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

I am building linux kernel, if my kernel under git, then kernel version every time is:

```
Image Name:   Linux-2.6.39+
```

If I am not using git, then everything is OK without any plus at the end.

I know that this done by scripts/setlocalversion script:

```
if test "$CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO" = "y"; then
    # full scm version string
    res="$res$(scm_version)"
else
    # append a plus sign if the repository is not in a clean
    # annotated or signed tagged state (as git describe only
    # looks at signed or annotated tags - git tag -a/-s) and
    # LOCALVERSION= is not specified
    if test "${LOCALVERSION+set}" != "set"; then
        scm=$(scm_version --short)
            res="$res${scm:++}"
        fi
fi
```

So, it is possible without code changes say to build system that no need to add "+" at the end of version line?

Comment: Set `LOCALVERSION`. Are you working off the `HEAD`, or have an unclean branch?

Comment: LOCALVERSION - Append an extra string to the end of your kernel version.

But I dont need append anything. I need just 2.6.39.

Comment: Did you consider building a more recent kernel. 2.6.39 is really old. Current one is 3.11.4 and has a lot of improvements (but stay compatible with 2.6.x)

Comment: Have found one ugly solution - add LOCALVERSION= to make command

Comment: What difficulty does having the appended `+` cause you?  It has a specific meaning, what you're doing will cause anything that cares to make bad decisions.

Comment: The "+" confusing some applications, for example "modprobe -l" in my case looking at  the 2.6.39 folder without plus at the end.

Answer (score 39):

The plus sign at the end of your version string is there as an indicator that the kernel was built from modified sources (that is, there were non-committed changes). This is also indicated by the comments in `scripts/setlocalversion`.

To avoid the '+' being appended despite having a dirty working directory, simply set LOCALVERSION explicityly when running `make`:

```
make LOCALVERSION=
```

You may also have to change the configuration option `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO` to `n` in your kernel config (`.config`) before building:

```
sed -i "s|CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=.*|CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=n|" .config
```

Comment: I do get a + at the end of  my `vmlinuz` and `initrd.img`, yet `git status` says "nothing to commit, working directory clean". It is my own commit though, does the + appear because I am not on the official master branch? Or maybe since I built locally the working directory is not clean although the dirt is gitignored?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.. You should have a look at `scripts/setlocalversion` and see exactly what it is testing for when setting `+`.

Comment: Apparently, it also adds a plus if your working directory is clean, but your current git HEAD has no tag.

Comment: Ah, but that's not all of it. I have my own branch, tagged commit, clean working dir, but I still get the +.

Comment: @Gauthier Same as you >_<

Answer (score 36):

To prevent the script `scripts/setlocalversion` to append the `+` to the end of the kernel local version, create an empty `.scmversion` file in the root of the kernel sources.

```
touch .scmversion
```

this way, you'll be able to leave LOCALVERSION as is in the kernel configuration file, in case you want to append a local signature to the kernel name.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating scripts/setlocalversion seems to be the only way for me. 
Force return in `scm_version()`:

```
scm_version()
{
        local short
        short=false
        **return**
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your local.conf if you're using yocto and imx soc

```
SCMVERSION_pn-linux-imx = ""
```

Tested on imx-4.9.88-2.0.0_ga release

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the line as a workaround/quickfix in scripts/setlocalversion. Then the kernel version should be same as "make kernelversion".

```
       # Check for git and a git repo.
        if test -z "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup 2>/dev/null)" &&
           head=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD 2>/dev/null); then

                # If we are at a tagged commit (like "v2.6.30-rc6"), we ignore
                # it, because this version is defined in the top level Makefile.
                if [ -z "$(git describe --exact-match 2>/dev/null)" ]; then

                        # If only the short version is requested, don't bother
                        # running further git commands
                        if $short; then
                                #echo "+" #comment this line
                                return
                        fi
```