# Installing Linux Kernel Modules without plus + (on ARM)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

Installing Linux Kernel Modules of Version `3.4.79`, but I always get a foulder with `3.4.79+`.

How can I install it without the `+`?

Doing it with

> make ARCH=arm INSTALL_MODULE_PATH=dest modules_install

Comment: Does the Makefile have `KERNELDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` or `KERNELDIR := /lib/modules/some-hardcoded-path/build`?

Comment: yes it's hardcoded path to kernel.release which contains a single word "3.4.79+". removed the "+". After the same "make ..." command I get at the end of makeprocess: DEPMOD 3.4.79+

Comment: Did you `make clean`?

Comment: i try to "make clean" before. the point is, that the kernel.release is generated (with the 3.4.79+) while the "make" process. so it´s a mistake while the "make" in the kernel source.

Comment: trying this post, will tell my result soon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333918/dont-add-to-linux-kernel-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
sed -i "s|CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=.*|CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=n|" .config && make LOCALVERSION=
```