# What is the difference between /lib/modules/version and /lib/modules/version+ (plus sign)?

Tags: linux, module, version, difference

Please help, who know between /lib/modules/version and /lib/modules/version+ (plus sign)
e.g. /lib/modules/3.4.61 and /lib/modules/3.4.61+.

Sorry my weak English and weak Linux (I am newbie).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Linux Kernel Modules without plus + (on ARM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608497/installing-linux-kernel-modules-without-plus-on-arm)

Comment: Thank you Stark for your quick reply, it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand the difference between **version** and **release**.
Version is a three fields value, like v5.0.1. We can have alternatives for the same version, especially on development.

As real example: Linus is now working to publish Linux v6.0.0. Before pushing it, he is making many 6.0.0 testing versions, we call it *release candidates*.

He releases each release candidate as v6.0.0rc2, then v6.0.0rc3, and it keeps increasing. The version prefix keeps the same, it only changes the release suffix (rcN). When its good enough, we releases the 'official' v6.0.0.
So, release is kind of 'version of a version'. Its a very specific moment/commit.

We can check version and release strings using `make -s kernelversion` and `make -s kernelrelease`.
*kernelrelease* is just *kernelversion* **concatenated** with a release suffix.

Kernelversion is extracted from the file `./Makefile`, from its first lines:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
VERSION = 6
PATCHLEVEL = 0
SUBLEVEL = 0
EXTRAVERSION =
```

Kernelversion is just these three first values separated by '.'.

Lets see `./scripts/setlocalversion` algorithm, he is the guy who tells its release suffix:

```
if [ -z "$(git describe --exact-match 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
    ...
    if $short; then
        echo "+"
        return
    fi
    ...
fi
```

Note that he checks `git describe`, if it doesn't return an annoted tag, it will return "+". That means, if the version is '6.0.0', it will become '6.0.0+'.

TUTORIAL

1. First thing we need, is to asure we have a git annoted tag, to avoid the '+'.
   Use

```
git tag -a mytag -m 'Commenting about this tag'
```

Now `./scripts/setlocalversion` may return nothing (empty).

2. Enable auto complement on `.config`.

```
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=""
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y
```

3. Make a file `.scmversion` with the suffix you want (if you want any).

```
echo 'mysuffix' > .scmversion
```

Now check it again with `make -s kernelrelease`. Its expected to be solved :)