# "dirty" string appending to kernel version while compiling in Jenkins environment

Tags: jenkins, linux-kernel, jenkins-pipeline

I know that, if there are any changes in git local depot and not in git repo (modified locally and not committed to git repo) then dirty string will append to kernel version string.
But here my question we are not maintaining our linux kernel code in git, we are maintain in perforce.
Recently I have checked-in few changes to linux kernel according to my requirement. I compiled code in my local setup, it went successful but in Jenkins environment kernel version is appending with "dirty" string.
I want to know why this is happening in jenkins

Answer (score 1):

I have found some meaning for that from one of the post. I will refer some links for more info. If you want, you can go and read it yourself. This is the most meaningful answer to your question that I found.

> From what I gather from reading the Git manual at the above link, the -dirty tag means:
>
> A working tree is said to be "dirty" if it contains
>   modifications which have not been committed to the current branch.
>
> So, to me that means you started with a particular branch of the kernel
>   (or some part of it) and then made some modifications to some code in
>   there, but did not commit those changes to the branch. The result is
>   that the build (or some part of it) is tagged as "dirty".
>
> If you Google for "dirty kernel tag" you can read some more about this
>   in the LKML mailing list threads.

Extra Links :

[what-is-dirty-kernel-version](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-is-dirty-kernel-version-797711/#post3911379)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194205

[Linux kernel : Kernel version string appended with either ''+" or "-dirty"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090803/linux-kernel-kernel-version-string-appended-with-either-or-dirty)