# Attempting to boot new uImage

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am attempting to boot uImage via uboot and I am getting some seemingly conflicting log info:

```
update Kernel1 tftp uImage-2.5 6.35. -digi-armv7a.LONEPEAK-Ver-4_33

Using FEC0 device

TFTP from server 10.12.1.77; our IP address is 10.12.1.205

Filename 'uImage-2.6.35-digi-armv7a.LONEPEAK-Ver-4_33'.

Load address: 0x94000000

Loading: #################################################################

     #################################################################

     ###########################################

done

Bytes transferred = 2533360 (26a7f0 hex)

Calculated checksum = 0x49669c61

Updating partition 'Kernel1'

Erasing 128 KiB @ 0x08540000:  0%          
Erasing 128 KiB @ 0x085e0000: 20%          
Erasing 128 KiB @ 0x08680000: 41%          
Erasing 128 KiB @ 0x08720000: 62%          
Erasing 128 KiB @ 0x087c0000: 83%          

Erasing:   complete                                      

Writing:  0%          
Writing: 51%          

Writing:   complete                                      

Verifying:  0%          
Verifying: 51%          

Verifying: complete                                      

Writing Parameters to NVRAM

Update successful
```

Above it shows a successful update but then when issue a reboot command I get:

```
scanning bus for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found

       scanning bus for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found


** Invalid boot device **

Booting partition 'Kernel0'

## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 90007fc0 ...

   Image Name:   Linux-2.6.35.14-tjerbmx51_0005+

   Created:      2018-10-16  21:35:37 UTC

   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)

   Data Size:    2533296 Bytes =  2.4 MB

   Load Address: 90008000

   Entry Point:  90008000

   Loading Kernel Image ... OK

OK


Starting kernel ...
```

So my question is:

Is there a way for me to version my kernel when I build it s/t I can set the 'Image Name' so that I know its my kernel being loaded and not some type of Legacy Image??

Comment: Title doesn't match actual question.

Comment: Your image file is of type uImage, which is created using the **mkimage** utility.  It's the `-n [image name]` option of **mkimage** that can customize the 'Image Name' contained in the header of the uImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`-option of Linux kernel `.config`-file will help you.

From the [Kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/admin-guide/README.html):

> Keep a backup kernel handy in case something goes wrong. This is
>   especially true for the development releases, since each new release
>   contains new code which has not been debugged. Make sure you keep a
>   backup of the modules corresponding to that kernel, as well. If you
>   are installing a new kernel with the same version number as your
>   working kernel, make a backup of your modules directory before you do
>   a make modules_install.
>
> Alternatively, before compiling, use the kernel config option
>   “LOCALVERSION” to append a unique suffix to the regular kernel
>   version. LOCALVERSION can be set in the “General Setup” menu.

So during the kernel configuration you can add some clear suffix to your kernel e.g. `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-test_some_stuff"`.

Some useful links: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194129/linux-kernel-version-suffix-config-localversion) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333918/dont-add-to-linux-kernel-version).